# Python Pandas libs problem with filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have written this search function for a dataframe:

```py
def search_for_name(name, data):
    print(name)
    dogs_with_name = data[data["HundenameText"].str.contains(name)]
    return dogs_with_name[["HundenameText", "GebDatHundJahr", "SexHundLang"]]
```

Unfortunately, this returns more records than I want, e.g. `Arina Luna` when I'm looking for `Luna`. I'm only interested in exact matches. How do I achieve that?

Comment: can you try: `dogs_with_name=data[data["HundenameText"]==name]`

Comment: Please edit your question to contain properly formatted code, this questions is likely to be removed as is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter Pandas Data Frame based on exact string match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164537/filter-pandas-data-frame-based-on-exact-string-match)